# Use of plural and singular for plural objects

Tags: gramática, plurales

I am learning Spanish with Collins Easy Learning Spanish.
It gives the follow example:

> The stairs are over there. = Las escaleras están allí.
>
> The stairs are over there, to your right. = La escalera está allí, a
>   su derecha.

Why does one use the plural form (`están`) and the other the singular form (`está`)?
I thought stairs would have to be in the plural, so shouldn't it always be `están`?

Comment: As both answers posted so far point, *escalera* is as correct as *escaleras*, hence **la escalera está** and **las escaleras están**. Which one to choose is a matter of taste (and local variations) rather than correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both work fine. *Escalera* can be used in the singular — equivalent to *staircase*— or the plural —equivalent to *stairs*

> **escalera** (DRAE 23.ª ed.)
>   **1.** *f.* Conjunto de peldaños o escalones que enlazan dos planos a distinto nivel en una construcción o terreno, y que sirven para subir y bajar. *U. t. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.*

That note at the end of the definition says "used also in the plural with the same meaning as in the singular".

Answer (score 3):

Escalera is one of those annoying words that are used as a singular or a plural noun. See [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G6uCj2q):

> 1. f. Conjunto de peldaños o escalones que enlazan dos planos a distinto nivel en una construcción o terreno, y que sirven para subir y bajar. **U. t. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.**